# I need SUM of values that are below 0 and greater than 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is how my code looks like:

```
SELECT p.productid AS 'Redni broj',
    p.code AS 'Sifra robe',
    p.unitname AS 'Jedinica mere',
    di.quantity AS 'Kolicina',
    di.price 'Stara cena',
    di.itemvalue 'Stari iznos',
    di.price2 AS 'Nova cena',
    (di.price2 * di.quantity) AS 'Novi iznos',
    (di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue) AS 'Difference',
    SUM(di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue > 0) AS 'Positive difference',
    SUM(di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue < 0) AS 'Negative Difference'
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN productcategorypr AS pc ON p.productid = pc.productid
LEFT JOIN documentitem AS di ON p.productid = di.productid
GROUP BY p.productid
```

I need to filter Diffrence to 2 columns, all differences that are below 0, and all differences that are above 0, difference is NewPrice - Old Price...

Comment: mysql and SQL server are different. Pick one

Answer (score 4):

This expression is incorrect:

```
SUM(di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue > 0) AS 'Positive difference'
```

You need to replace it with a `CASE` expression:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN di.price2 * di.quantity > di.itemvalue THEN di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue ELSE 0 END) AS 'Positive difference'
```

Do the same thing with `Negative difference` expression:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN di.price2 * di.quantity < di.itemvalue THEN di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue ELSE 0 END) AS 'Negative Difference'
```

Answer (score 0):

SUM( CASE WHEN (di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue) > 0 THEN (di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Positive Difference'

SUM( CASE WHEN (di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue) < 0 THEN (di.price2 * di.quantity - di.itemvalue) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Negative Difference'